# How can I linearize sine-Gordon PDE to apply Von Neumann stability analysis?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-theory, linearization, finite-difference-methods

Specifically, I have this equation

$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}(x, t) =  \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}(x, t) -sen(u(x, t)); \quad L_{0} \le x \le L_{1}; \quad
t \geq t_{0}$

and them I applied the finite difference method and found this

$U^{i + 1}_{j} = v^2U^{i}_{j + 1} + (2 - 2v^2)U^{i}_{j} + v^2U^{i}_{j - 1} - U^{i - 1}_{j} -k^2\sin{\left(U^{i}_{j}\right)}$

$k$ and $h$ are my discretizations in time and space respectialy, $v = \frac{k}{h}$ is the courant number, $U^{i}_{j} \approx u(x_j, t_i)$

I want to know the contitions this equation is stable. To do that, I want to linearize it and apply the Von Neumann stability analysis. Can someone help me to do that ?